# Tensorflow image retraining has SystemError: built-in function delete_Status> returned a result with an error set

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was running the default example provided at

https://github.com/eldor4do/Tensorflow-Examples/blob/master/retraining-example.py

However, it returned a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-04e0fd4afe9a>", line 3, in <module>
    {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

  File "/storage/programfiles/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 340, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "/storage/programfiles/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 564, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)

  File "/storage/programfiles/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 637, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)

  File "/storage/programfiles/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 644, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)

  File "/storage/programfiles/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 628, in _run_fn
    session, None, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, None)

SystemError: <built-in function delete_Status> returned a result with an error set
```

There seems to be no help on this particular issue. Can anyone provide some much needed assistance? :)

On a related note, if anyone can point me to an example where i can feed multiple images to the imagenet model and attain the results, instead of one by one via bazel, that will be immensely useful! :)

thank you!!

Comment: Not directly related but perhaps this might help? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/830

Comment: hey thanks for your reply! :) I saw that link, and my swig is updated but the error still persists